# Can I re-submit at editorial manager?

Tags: paper-submission

For the journal I am submitting to, I need to use both platforms `cmt3.research.microsoft.com` and `editorialmanager.com`.
I am familiar with the first, but not the latter.
In the first, I am able to delete my PDF manuscript and reupload it before the deadline.
Thus, I can work on it until the last version, but are sure that I've got a working copy online in case something unforeseen happens (e.g. I get sick).
Can I do the same (deleting and re-uploading before the deadline) with the `editorialmanager.com`?

Note, that I am not talking about the process after the reviewers received my manuscript the first time, but before the very first submission deadline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I *am* the wiser:

When in the main menu

[image]

one presses on "Submit New Manuscript".
Then one lead through a series of forms one has to fill out and can press "Save & Submit Later". After than one can still change things, the contents is just saved to work on it the next day:

[image]

Alternatively one can press "Build PDF for Approval".
This builds a PDF that combines the documents from "Attach Files".
After that one *still* is able to modify the submission.
However, one *still* has *not* submitted!

After pressing "Build PDF for Approval", you get to a page where you have some "Action Links" left to your submission:

[image]

When you press "Action Links" you can edit the submission or "approve as an author" (or something along those lines).
Only after you have approved the submission as an author your submission is complete and goes to the reviewers; however, now you cannot edit the submission anymore.
You could only delete the submission and submit again - but from what I've read online, this should only been done if really necessary.